# How to set the width of all the traces together to the desired value before using autoroute option in Autodesk Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, trace, via, autorouter

How to set the width of all the traces together to the desired value before using autoroute option in Autodesk Eagle?

every time I use autoroute, the trace width is by default set to 0.0154mm. I have tried changing the value in design rules. However, I didn't find any luck. I am trying to set the value of trace width to 13mil and drill size to 24 mils. Can you please suggest the exact way to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is done with *classes*.  Do HELP CLASS.  There is also a global minimum trace width specified in the DRC settings.

Each net has a class.  Classes have properties like the minimum trace width and clearance from other traces.

You'd typically use this mechanism by creating a class for the high voltage AC input lines, the high current main power supply, ordinary signals, etc.  It's common to have 3 to 6 classes in a design.